# Eclipse AST parser not preserving static import

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I pray that you are well.

I am trying to write a QuickFix plugin in Eclipse for "not found" imports. As part of this, I am trying to generate an AST with a variety of different import statement types. I am trying to avoid setting up a full-blown Eclipse workspace to perform the test.

The code to fire up the parser and produce an AST is pretty simple. However, I have found that the parser does not honour the "static" keyword on the imports. So if I find an ImportDeclaration on the generated AST, its isStatic() property will be false even if the source contained "import static ...", and if I dump the contents of the CompilationUnit I can see that the "static" keyword has been dropped.

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setSource("import static java.util.Collections.*;".toCharArray());
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
System.err.println(cu); // prints "import java.util.Collections.*;"*
```

I tried to get around this problem by generating the AST directly instead of via the parser. I can then call "setStatic(true)" on the `ImportDeclaration` to set its static flag. This generates the correct structure:

```
AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS8);
CompilationUnit cu = ast.newCompilationUnit();
ImportDeclaration dec = ast.newImportDeclaration();
dec.setName(ast.newName("java.util.Collections"));
dec.setStatic(true);
dec.setOnDemand(true);
cu.imports().add(dec);
System.err.println(cu); //  prints "import static java.util.Collections.*;"
```

However, `dec.getStartPosition()` is set to -1 and `dec.getLength()` returns 0, presumably as they don't correspond to any particular source. This messes up my QuickFix processor, which needs to know where in the source they appear to work. I can try and manually set all of the set and end positions, but I was kinda hoping that's what the parser should be doing.

Any suggestions? Is it a simple parser configuration option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wouldn't you know it - I researched this for a good day or so before posting the question on Stack Overflow and then found the answer myself a few minutes after posting...

For the benefit of anyone else who should stumble across this question: The missing link is that the "import static" syntax only became available in Java 1.5 and higher, and by default the compiler was using a lower java version (perhaps 1.0?). Adding the following code to my first example fixed the problem:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
Map options = JavaCore.getOptions(); // New!
JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options); // New!
parser.setCompilerOptions(options); // New!
parser.setSource("import static java.util.Collections.*;".toCharArray());
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
System.err.println(cu); // prints "import static java.util.Collections.*;"
```

I had incorrectly assumed that setting `AST.JLS8` in the call to `newParser()` would take care of that, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: You saved the day man. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!